# How to use google authentication for an angular web app and a .net web api hosted on azure

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, google-signin, google-authentication

I have an angular web app talking to a c# .net web api back end.
They are both hosted on azure app services. 
Azure app services offers a suite of authentication services and I've chosen to use google auth.
I've got my google client id and secret setup in azure google auth and my web app correctly shows and prompts me for my google credentials.
My problem now, is that i need my web api back end to authenticate the web app google token. I couldn't find any articles or tutorials that demonstrates the following:

How to get and send the token to the web api? I've read that azure app service should automatically inject the necessary auth headers but any calls to my api do not include those headers. Should i manually call auth/me and add them to the request header?

How do i get my web api to authenticate the details from the request header with google auth? Do i need a separate client id for the web api or should i re-use the web app client id?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that you are using the built-in [Authentication / Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) provided by Azure App Service.

AFAIK, App Service Authentication (Easy Auth) provides two flows: client-managed and server-managed flow. For the server-managed flow, the server code manages the sign-in process for you, and your backend would directly receive the token from the relevant identity provider (e.g. Google, AAD,etc.), then both generate a `authenticationToken` for browser-less apps and `AppServiceAuthSession` cookie for browser apps. Details you could follow [Authentication flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview#authentication-flow).

For your angular web app, you could just use server-managed flow, after user successfully logged, you need to call `https://<your-angular-app-name>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me` to retrieve the google `access_token`, then send the following request against your web api endpoint for retrieving the `authenticationToken` as follows:

```
POST https://<your-webapi-app-name>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google
Body {"access_token":"<the-google-access-token>"}
```

After successfully retrieved the `authenticationToken` from your Web API endpoint, you could send the following subsequent requests for accessing your APIs:

```
GET https://<your-webapi-app-name>.azurewebsites.net/api/values
Header x-zumo-auth:"<authenticationToken-generated-by-your-webapi>"
```

Moreover, you could also use client-managed flow in your angular web app, you may need to directly contact with your identity provider (Google) to retrieve the access_token in your client via [Auth0](https://auth0.com/authenticate/angularjs/google-apps/) or [google-signin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin) or other third-party libraries. Then you may need to both send request to your angular web app and Web API web app for retrieving the `authenticationToken` as the above request sample.

> Do i need a separate client id for the web api or should i re-use the web app client id?

Per my understanding, you must use the same google application. For AAD authentication, you could configure a AAD app with the access permissions to another AAD app.